# How to extract an element from nested list, and append it to another list?

Tags: python

```
lst =[[1,2,'a'],[3,4,'b'],[5,6,'c'],[7,8,'d']]

result = [[1,3,5,7],[2,4,6,8],['a','b','c','d']]
```

I need to get result list from lst. Is there any way to get the result list.. Irrespective of length of nested list.

Answer (score 3):

You should be using [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) here:

```
>>> lst =[[1,2,'a'],[3,4,'b'],[5,6,'c'],[7,8,'d']]

# Python 2.7
>>> result = zip(*lst)
>>> result
[(1, 3, 5, 7), (2, 4, 6, 8), ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')]
```

In Python 3+, `zip` returns generator object. In order to get the value as `list`, you have to explicitly type-cast it as:

```
# In Python3+
>>> list(zip(*lst))
[(1, 3, 5, 7), (2, 4, 6, 8), ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
listLen,listElemLen = len(lst), len(lst[0])
res = []
for i in range(listElemLen):
     temp = []
     for j in range(listLen):
        temp.append(lst[j][i])
     res.append(temp)
print(res) #[[1,3,5,7],[2,4,6,8],['a','b','c','d']]
```

Comment: I believe an indentation error snuck in to your code when you copied it into the answer, `res.append(temp)` should be outside the inner for-loop.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Ah. yes. Thank you for pointing it out. Edited.